# which dlls are being used?

Tags: windows, dll

please forgive my windows ignorance,

Is there an application which can show me which dlls an executable is attempting to use (name, path)

I'm assuming this can be done via static analysis of executable and/or when the executable is running by examining system calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: I'm a fan of SysInternals too - the Swiss Army Chainsaw collection of tools that should have been included with Windows from the start. But I admit that Dependency Walker is probably the more luxurious solution for this special purpose.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz never used it, sysInternals always been enough for me but I will have a look at dep walker

Comment: @redsquare: The main difference is that Dependency Walker tells you about the dependencies a particular EXE or DLL has, so you can figure out why it won't start, or what you'd need to ship with it. Process Explorer can tell you what libraries are loaded, once a process has been started, but it has to start for that purpose. Process Monitor will tell you what goes on at the OS interface, but figuring out the same things Dependency Walker just _tells_ you, can sometimes be cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

> Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules. For each module found, it lists all the functions that are exported by that module, and which of those functions are actually being called by other modules. Another view displays the minimum set of required files, along with detailed information about each file including a full path to the file, base address, version numbers, machine type, debug information, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency walker

It's fabulous, and lets you see the hierarchy of dependent DLL's. It also shows you functions that the DLL exports.
I've even used it to solve mysterious Error 127 problems.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/